# Route conditionally load jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, routes

In my AngularJS app I have one route that depends on jquery and jquery ui. I want to avoid the extra 150 kb.

Is it possible to load jquery and jquery ui only for that particular route?

Comment: Try to add these scripts in the corresponding view file.

Comment: This doesn't work since all the angular stuff is already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Create one header view which have jquery scripts and one view with all angular stuffs.
Then in your normal routes, include the second header in the corresponding view and in the jquery required route, you have to include both headers.

Use [ng-include](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude).